# How to use WWW:Mechanize to login

Tags: perl

I want to login to a persian blogging service . This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;

$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$url =  "http://blogfa.com/Desktop/Login.aspx?t=1";
$mech->get($url);

$result = $mech->submit_form(
form_name => 'aspnetForm', #name of the form
#instead of form name you can specify
#form_number => 1
fields      =>
{
 'master$ContentPlaceHolder1$Uid'    => 'my username', # name of the input field and value
 'master$ContentPlaceHolder1$Password'    => 'my password',
}
,'master$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit'    => 'ورود به بخش مدیریت' #name of the submit button
);

  $result->content();
if ($result =~ /میز کار/) {
print "Done\n"; }
else {
print "Failed!\n"; }
```

But it doesn't work at all. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `WWW:Mechanize` does not execute javascript. Since the site you want to log in uses javascript for logging in, its not able to do that.

You could fix that problem by using [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox), which allows you to execute javascript.

Comment: I am trying to install `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` but failing with all the dependencies...I have no clue what is happening here...

Comment: do you have Firefox installed? - Which dependencies failed?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS with firefox installed.

Comment: I am installing the module as 

`sudo cpan install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`

Here are the dependencies - 

Can't locate Spiffy.pm / Test::Base and lot of other modules

Comment: Even I am NOT able to install `HTML::Selector::XPath` which is one of the dependent module

Comment: i have installed it via `App::cpanminus` : `cpanm WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`, worked perfectly.

Comment: I will try this Paul.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get("http://blogfa.com/Desktop/Login.aspx?t=1");

$mech->submit_form(

    with_fields => {
        'master$ContentPlaceHolder1$Uid'       => 'my username',
        'master$ContentPlaceHolder1$Password'  => 'my password',
    },
    button => 'master$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit',
);
```